# Como recibir un array asociativo?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Lo que quiero hacer es recibir un array asociativo como respuesta de una petición ajax pero lo que obtengo es el siguiente mensaje "commerce_brandconectado a base de datosArray
"
recibo el array pero al final del resultado lo que quiero es obtener solo el array para recorrerlo en el archivo js.

> archivo js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("hola");
let selectCards =$('#cards');  
let selectEstados =  $('#estados');
let columna = 'commerce_brand';
//let selectCards = document.querySelector('#cards');

function cargarOpciones (idSelectIndependiente, columna, idSelectDependiente){
console.log(idSelectIndependiente);
console.log("entrando");



$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'cargar_estados.php',
        data:{
                'peticion': 'idSelectIndependiente',
                'num':columna
            }
        //dataType:'json'
    })

    .done(function(lista_rep1){

        console.log("sd "+lista_rep1);

        idSelectIndependiente.empty();
        idSelectIndependiente.append('<option value="">Elige una opcion</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < lista_rep1.length; i++) {

          idSelectIndependiente.append("<option value='lista_rep1[i][commerce_brand]'>lista_rep1[i][commerce_brand]</option>");
        //idSelectIndependiente.append('<option value="'+lista_rep1[i]['id']+'">'+lista_rep1[i][1]+'</option>');
            //$row[commerce_region]

    };

    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('error al cargar las listas');
    });
console.log("saliendo");
}

cargarOpciones(selectCards, columna)
```

> archivo .php

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

$cards = $_POST['peticion'];
$columna = $_POST['num'];
echo $columna;




function getData($idSelect = false, $columna){

    switch ($columna){
        case 'commerce_brand':
            $con = getCon();
            $query = "SELECT commerce_brand FROM `commerc` group by commerce_brand";
            $result = $con->query($query);
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            //$listas = "<option value='$row[commerce_brand]'>$row[commerce_brand]</option>";
            return $row;
        break;

        default:
            $probando = "viene por defecto";
        return $probando;
    }
}

echo getData($cards,$columna);
```

Comment: intenta formatear el resultado con un json_encode y comenta como te va... saludos.

Comment: me muestra el siguiente mensaje 'commerce_brandconectado a base de datos{"commerce_brand":"MASTERCARD"} lo que quiero es obtener solo el json
'

Comment: creo que ese mensaje no corresponde al return de la funcion getData(), pienso que deberia quedar algo como...

echo json_encode(getData($cards,$columna));
die();

Answer (score 0):

Ese mensaje parece ser de un `echo` para depurar el resultado, como si hubieses puesto algo así:

```
echo "commerce_brand";
...
echo "conectado a base de datos";
...
echo $array;
```

Todos estas salidas influyen en la forma en que se escribirá la respuesta del archivo php. Es posible que ese echo esté en la función `getCon()`.

Te sugiero revisar el código para revisar dónde pueden haber salidas así, y en todo caso, imprimir la respuesta usando la función `json_encode()` en la llamada de la función `getData()`. Adicionalmente, deberías meter el mensaje de error en un arreglo asociativo para que la respuesta venga en frmato JSON:

```
function getData($idSelect = false, $columna){

    switch ($columna){
        ...
        default:
            $error= array("error" => "viene por defecto");
            return $error;
    }
}

// Codificación de la salida en formato JSON
echo json_encode(getData($cards,$columna));
```

Así, la respuesta con `json_encode()` sería:

```
{"error":"viene por defecto"}
```